# Spritekit ground not touching bottom of screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a spritekit game and it all is working correctly, yet my ground is in the middle of the simulators screen. I have tried everything to make it be at the bottom of the screen. one function.

```
let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
groundTexture.filteringMode = .nearest

for i in stride(from: 0, to: 2 + self.frame.size.width / groundTexture.size().width, by: 1) {

    let ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
    ground.zPosition = 1.0 //-10
    //ground.position = CGPoint(x: (groundTexture.size().width / 2.0 + (groundTexture.size().width * CGFloat(i))), y: groundTexture.size().height / 4.0) //original position 

    ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: groundTexture.size().height / +0)  //tried this from a tutorial 
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width * 2.0, height: groundTexture.size().height / 4.0)) //erase  * 4 test
    ground.setScale(1.2)
    ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation  = false
    ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory 

    //contact and collision bitmask 
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | enemy1Category | enemy2Category | enemy3Category | enemy4Category | obstacleCategory | coinCatergory
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCategory | enemy1Category | enemy2Category | enemy3Category | enemy4Category | obstacleCategory | coinCatergory
    ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    self.addChild(ground)

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 5)
    let moveReset = SKAction.moveBy(x: groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    let moveLoop = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, moveReset])
    let moveForever = SKAction.repeatForever(moveLoop)

    ground.run(moveForever)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a scene's `anchorPoint` coordinates are 0, 0 unless otherwise specified. `anchorPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` is the center of the screen. You are not specifying a position for your ground so it gets automatically added to the scenes anchorPoint (which is the middle of the screen).

You need to either change the scenes anchorPoints to the bottom of the screen or adjust the ground position accordingly such as...

```
ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.size.width / 2 + ground.size.width / 2, y: 0 - self.size.height / 2 + ground.size.height / 2)
```

(the above example assumes you are adding the ground in the scene and self = scene)

for your reference...

[image]